# Word to describe metal tablets that have bevelled edges?

Tags: single-word-requests

Especially in digital graphic design (I want to describe 2-dimensional images, not the real-life objects they depict).

For some reason I thought that could be called an "embossed" square.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

What's a word that can describe these kinds of graphical elements? Especially the "outset" ones (the one there labelled "inset" is not exactly what I want to describe, but obviously very related so maybe the correct word describes both).

> The __________ square

I want to describe specifically that the edges rise from a 0-height on the outside to the same height as the inside of the button.

So I do not want the word to also describe these:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What's wrong with "beveled"?

Comment: What is metal tablet?

Comment: @TinfoilHat I couldn't think of a better word than that to describe those pictures and the vivid images I have in my head. "a flat slab of stone, clay, or wood, used especially for an inscription" - oxford languages

Comment: @TinfoilHat also like rectangular medicine or sweet tablets (dextrose energy?)

Comment: It is important to state whether the figures illustrated are simply two-dimensional prints or, in fact three-dimensional objects.

Comment: @Greybeard two-dimensional prints

Comment: [this SE question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/40053/will-removing-the-border-bevel-on-these-buttons-make-them-look-un-buttonlike) talks about bevels; I think "beveled" is the word if you're talking about UI design. Obviously if you're talking about stone masonry, there may be other terminology, but it's unlikely to be as familiar.

Comment: The "metal" element is misleading to the question. The "material" of the  **3D image** could be wood, plastic, or ice (translucent). You want the word that describes the shadow effect when  the 3D button  is raised *above* the surface, and when it is *buried* or *pushed* in.

Comment: @Mari-LouA you're right that it doesn't have to be metal, but actually i don't want to describe drop shadow at all, i want to describe the edge styling

Comment: @Laurel I think I normally hear "bevelled edge", not "bevelled square" or "bevelled tablet", so I think it specifically describes edges and would be incorrect to apply to the item overall

Answer (score 3):

In web design, the word for a two-dimensional projection that appears to be a button is "buttonization" This term refers to the result of the process of making an object or image appear as if it can be clicked or pressed like a physical button.

> **buttonize** [WordSense.eu](https://www.wordsense.eu/buttonizing/)
>
> To apply bevelled edges to (a visual element), giving it the appearance of a push-button.

In addition to buttonization, other related terms include "buttonify" and "buttonize". These terms are often used interchangeably with buttonization, depending on the context and the specific application.  If you want to include the appearance of depressed cavities in the term, then "projection" is the term that best fits.

> **projection** [JavaTPoint](https://www.javatpoint.com/computer-graphics-projection)
>
> ...the process of converting a 3D object into a 2D object. It is also defined as mapping or transformation of the object in projection plane or view plane.

Comment: Hello, Paris. You can find a definition of the verb on the internet; answers supported by such references (quote, attribution and link) are seen as optimal (if not de rigueur) on ELU, and attract more upvotes.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome and protocol orientation, Edwin.  I see I can edit my reply, so I will add the links.

Answer (score 1):

If it stands out from the surrounding surface, it is embossed.

OED **embossed**

> 1. Carved or moulded in relief; ornamented with figures in relief; (of figures or ornament) raised, standing out in relief.   embossed
>    printing n. printing with raised letters, as for the use of blind
>    people, or for ornament.

If it appears to be below the surface, it is imprinted

OED **imprinted**

> **1.a.** transitive. **To mark by pressure; to impress, stamp (a figure, etc. on something); to delineate by pressure.**

The first group are embossed with rounded edges

The third image - a square - is embossed and bevelled.

OED **bevel** (v.)

> **1.** transitive. **To cut away or otherwise bring to a slope; to reduce (a square edge) to a more obtuse angle**

**inset** and **outset** are printing terms.

The **inset** is said to be impressed with bevelled edges.

The **outset** is said to be embossed with bevelled edges.

Answer (score 1):

If the tablet is mobile (you can press it or somehow interact with it), [*button*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/607929/371882) is the word.

If the tablet is fixed, you could call it a ***plaque***:

> a flat piece of metal, stone, wood, or plastic with writing on it that is attached to a wall, door, or other object *"There was a brass plaque outside the door listing the various dentists' names."*; *"
> The First Lady unveiled a commemorative plaque."* [-Cambridge.org](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/plaque)

Since this seems to be for some sort of UI, without any real metal or bone, stick to the words already in use in the framework that you are using. The items on the right, for example, look like nineties' style info boxes or *non-editable text boxes*.

Comment: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/78798/whats-the-difference-between-cards-panels-and-tiles

Answer (score 1):

*raised* (or *recessed*) panels, squares, rectangles, etc.

I think most people are very familiar with those terms (*raised* is above the surrounding area, and *recessed* is below it) and the concepts via cabinet door construction, and entry doors to a lesser extent (raised or recessed vs. flat panel doors).

Comment: Computer buttons and keys are not raised or recessed.

Comment: +1 for panels, which is giving me serious nineties vibes (I think it was from reading the MS VB manuals, unfortunately. Who do I talk to, to get my time back?)

Comment: @Conrado - Thanks, but I don't really know what the OP means since the edit. Editing for clarity for all is hard though. Maybe it's the bottom layer of a stepped pyramid now…

Answer (score 0):

Buttons with rounded corners
Buttons with square corners

For example: See this site:

[The Rounded User Experience](https://prototypr.io/post/the-rounded-user-experience)

Square-cornered button
Round-cornered button

And this sister site: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/40744/mixing-rounded-corners-and-square-corners

Comment: The OP wants to describe the shading that produces the 3D effect, not the shape of the button corners.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie This is what s/he said: (I want to describe 2-dimensional images, not the real-life objects they depict). Which they describe as: metal tablets with beveled edges. Where do they even mention shading? The language in the question is all off.

Comment: A "metal tablet with beveled edges" is certainly a button of some sort _if it moves_. The ones on the left with filleted corners are forever doomed to be buttons in a UI, since Xerox / PARC [immortalized](https://arstechnica.com/features/2005/05/gui/3/) them this way. +1.

Answer (score -1):

The square in *relief*.

See definitions 6 and 7 here:
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/relief